# How to solve error "Thread 1: Signal SIGBART" after adding native video and exceptions wont work

Tags: ios, xcode, runtime-error, signals, breakpoints

im trying to add a video to a button click (native video) i had the code down perfect and it compiles and runs ok but when i click on that button thats meant to natively play the video... it gives me a "Thread 1: Signal SIGBART" ??? how can i fix this please?

i have followed everything as i should, imported the video into supporting files and made sure to give it the same name in .m as its file name.

Tried adding a breakpoint exception but wont work

here is the code in .h

```
@interface ViewController5 : UIViewController {

}

-(IBAction)play;

@end
```

here is the code in .m

```
@implementation ViewController5

-(IBAction)play {
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                     pathForResource:@"test video" ofType:@"mp4"]];
MPMoviePlayerViewController *playercontroller = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]
                                                 initWithContentURL:url];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:playercontroller];
playercontroller.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
[playercontroller.moviePlayer play];
playercontroller = nil;
}

@end
```

And here is the "green" highlight signal i get

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
@autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using ARC, you should keep a reference to `MPMoviePlayerViewController` instance so it's not deallocated when `play` method returns, and don't set it to `nil`.

```
// ViewController5.h
@interface ViewController5 : UIViewController {
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *playercontroller;
}
- (IBAction)play;
@end

// ViewController5.m
@implementation ViewController5
- (IBAction)play {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test video" ofType:@"mp4"]];
    playercontroller = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:playercontroller];
    playercontroller.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
    [playercontroller.moviePlayer play];
}
@end
```

Comment: i added that to the .h file instead of what i had and it still gives me this same breakpoint error... int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
   }

Comment: Yes, and don't define a local `MPMoviePlayerViewController` instance.

Comment: You also said i shouldnt set it to nil ? are you talking about the .m file and what should i set it to? how can i fix this whole thing... your help is much appreciated btw

Comment: Yes, don't set `playercontroller` to `nil` in `play` method.

Comment: also adding what you said has given me a bunch of orange highlight erros i didnt have before specifically to the last 4 lines of code in the .m file

Comment: if not nil what should i set it to or replace nil with ?

Comment: is it too much to ask of you to replace whats needed in both the .h file and .m file and then preview it on here so that i understand you better ?

Comment: i updated the .h file with the answer you just updated but it still gives me the same green breakpoint error and also a bunch of orange errors i didnt have before

Comment: ok i added your update to the .m file and now i have less orange errors however i still get the same green breakpoint signal when i click on the button thats supposed to "natively" play the test video. i connected the play outlet to the button followed by touch up inside... runs fine but when i click that button, same green breakpoint

Comment: int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}

Comment: thats the breakpoint error i keep getting so it wont play the video when i click the button thats supposed to play the test video it just goes back to the breakpoint in Xcode along with 2 warnings

Comment: warning: Unsupported Configuration: Scene is unreachable due to lack of entry points and does not have an identifier for runtime access via -instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:.

Comment: Scene is unreachable due to lack of entry points and does not have an identifier for runtime access via -instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:.

Comment: i have taken the screenshot through Xcode but how do i post it?

Comment: Edit the question and add the image.

Comment: i figured how to post it but when i take the screenshot in Xcode... where does it save? i cant find it in the native xcode folder for the app im working on ...

Comment: however in the last section of the post i added the green breakpoint error i get thats the exact thing im still getting now

Comment: the code we have used is PERFECt.... however i just tested something out, the short landscape video i recorded with the iphone which is a.mov file keeps giving me that green breakpoint error however the one i recorded with the iPad plays fine... also a .mov file ?? How is this ?